# How to use css image sprites in this code?

Tags: html, css

i was editing a template and there were around 50 images, so i put all the images into a Image Sprite

so the css is looks like this

```
.img_set_1 {
   background: url(../images/csg-4e1827fd5b201.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.img_set_1-button_menu_left{ background-position: 0 -256px; width: 19px; height: 29px; }
```

the old css file contains this kind of lines and How to modify below line to get image from sprite?

```
a.blackbutton span { margin:0; padding:7px 0 7px 19px; background:url(images/button_menu_left.gif) no-repeat top left;}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend using a tool that GOOGLE suggest to use

http://spriteme.org/

run the script on ur page and it will generate everything for you, great script!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. generating sprite is not a problem though. problem is getting image from sprite for above code.